# Why does this mathematical series plateau below $\frac{1}{4}$ then have runaway growth?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, recursion

This recursive mathematical series plateaus when $x \leq 1/4$, and it then goes runaway growth. Why?

```
x = 1/4
y = 0
for i in range(10000000):
    y = (x + y)**2
```

Comment: It doesn't depend on the i, just showing that its a recursive series. So, y = (x + y)**2 is called a few thousand times

Comment: python has to declare a "i" for the processor to be able to count in the loop. it would have to do so even if it did not force it to be declared explicitly in the code.

Comment: it's a recursive series. it isn't the same expression, since it is a series. y is always the result of the previous iteration. I'm just writing it out as a python function instead of mathematical series notation because I'm more used to that.

Comment: It's not the same result, it changes at every iteration

Comment: Yeah, I realised that I misread the thing. Now I understand. So basically you're trying to evaluate something like
$$
y_{n+1} = \left(x_0+ y_n\right)^2
$$, right? If you're looking for stable points for this, you could set $y_{n+1}=y_n =y$ and solve the equation.

Comment: What is the condition for $y_n\gt y_{n-1}$? (Indexing the values of $y$)

Comment: A graph will be useful: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qpp3wt3h82

Answer (score 3):

As a remark, you seem to implicitely only allow non-negative $x$ (setting say $x=-1000$ certainly leads to a runaway growth of $y$), so I'll keep that restriction.

So why is there no runaway growth for $0 \le x \le \frac14$?

As Matti.P wrote in a comment, your loop code would mathematically be described as a seqeunce: $y_0=0;\; y_{i+1}=(x+y_i)^2$ for all $i=0,1,2,\ldots$.

You start with $y_0 = 0 \le \frac14$.

Whenever you do the next loop iteration, and start with an $y_i$ that fulfills $0 \le y_i \le \frac14$, then the next $y_{i+1}$ fulfills the same condition!

Let's prove it. From

$$ 0 \le x+y_i \le \frac14 + \frac14 =\frac12,$$

which comes from using $0 \le x \le \frac14$ and $0 \le y_i \le \frac14$, we can immediately conclude, as the function $f(t)=t^2$ is increasing for $0 \le t$, that

$$ 0^2=0 \le y_{i+1}=(x+y_i)^2 \le \frac14 = \left(\frac12\right)^2.$$

So if $0 \le x \le \frac14$ and because we start with an $y$ value that is between $0$ and $\frac14$, all the following $y$-values will also stay in that interval.

To see why there is runaway growth for $x > \frac14$, we need a little bit more theory.

First, for all $x>0$ the sequence of $(y_i)$ will be increasing. It's true for the very first step from $y_0$ to $y_1$:

$$y_0=0; y_1=x^2 > 0.$$

And it keeps true from one step to the next:

if $0 \le y_i < y_{i+1}$, then

$$y_{i+1}=(x+y_i)^2 < (x+y_{i+1})^2 = y_{i+2},$$

again using the (strict) monotonicity of $f(t)=t^2$ for $t \ge 0$.

So $(y_n)$ is increasing for $x>0$. Such sequences can only have 2 behaviours:

- they converge to a limit, or
- they increase beyond all bounds and "converge" to $+\infty$.

We've seen above that for $0 \le x \le \frac14$ there is no increase beyond all bounds, so it must converge to a limit $l(x)$. How can this limit be calculated?

Well if we know (or assume) that $\lim_{i\to\infty}y_i=l(x)$, then we know that

$$l(x)=\lim_{i\to\infty}y_i = \lim_{i\to\infty}y_{i+1} = \lim_{i\to\infty} (x+y_i)^2 =(x+l(x))^2,$$

where the last equality used the fact that the function $g(t)=(x+t)^2$ is continous ($x$ is just a constant for that function). As we can see, this yields a quadratic equation for $l(x)$, which you can solve the usual way and get

$$l(x)=\frac{1-2x}2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-4x}4}$$

Which of the 2 values is actually the limit depends on $y_0$, but this is not our concern here. Note that the term under the square root is $\frac{1-4x}4$. That means the square root exists (in real numbers) only when $x \le \frac14$. If $x >\frac14$, the square root is complex and the only solutions to the equation are 2 non-real numbers.

But obviously, our sequence contains only real numbers, so the limit (if it exists) must be a real number. So the only conclusion we can draw is that for $x > \frac14$, the sequence $(y_n)$ has no limit.

But as I wrote above, for increasing sequences there are only 2 kinds of behaviours, and one has just been ruled out. So it has to be the other, which is unbounded growth.